# Double slash in URL is automatically converted in single slash in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am working on one site where I need to show 404 pages when someone adds double slash in URL.

I have written logic to check REQUEST_URI and if there is double slash then I am showing 404 pages...

But when I add double slash in URL it shows single slash in REQUEST_URI but in URL, it is double slash...

here I attached a screenshot for the same issue.

> For Example: if i enter **www.example.com//check** -> then its is coming
>   as **/check** in **REQUEST_URI** but i want it should come as **//check**
>
> Site is hosted in **AWS cloud load balancer (ELB)**. in local setting its
>   working proeper but in production its creating issue.

Can someone help me how can I prevent this?

[image]

Comment: It's standard normalization of the path, why would you want this (and not use some other method to solve whatever problem you're trying to fix)?

Comment: how can I prevent this normalization? @wurtel

Comment: problem is in google crawler its showing same page as duplicate content so we need to show 404 pages whenever double slash comes in url @wurtel

Comment: Have you considered that it might be your Amazon Load Balancer?

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that Google has indexed the double slash version as well as the regular path, then it's better to use a redirect to send google to the correct path.

As you tagged this question with nginx, the easiest solution is to use a selective rewrite, such as:

```
location / {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^//) {
        rewrite ^/.* $uri permanent;
    }
    [...]
}
```

This works because `$request_uri` is the original URI, while $uri is the normalized one. The rewrite statement replaces the complete URI with the normalized one, so that Google knows that the double slash version is to be replaced by the normalized one.

Comment: I have added same but it is not working too

Comment: i think $request_uri   its also coming as single slash

Comment: I have checked in nginx too $request_uri  also coming with a single slash so the problem is somewhere else

Comment: i think AWS load balancer is removing  double slash .... any idea how can i stop this

Comment: I had tested this first on my own nginx so I know the solution works; I have no idea whether it's possible to change how the AWS load balancer handles this. You could try using google webmaster tools to remove the wrong path.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=166461

this is the same issue I am facing

Comment: can you help me with anything in elb?